Azure ARM dependsOn Graphing tool
I have some fairly complex deployment scripts written in Bicep. It would be really helpful to visualize the "dependsOn: []" graph in the ARM file (or Bicep). Is there a tool to do this?

the bicep extension in vs code has this feature

bicep visualizer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/visual-studio-code?tabs=CLI#open-bicep-visualizer

Thanks @Thomas
As Mention in document you can visualize the Bicep
in VS code.
Below is my given code for function app.
which depends on App service plan and application insights
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param name string = 'webapp13aug'


resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-12-01' = {
  name: 'ASP-${name}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'P3v2'
    tier: 'PremiumV3'
    capacity: 1
  }
}

resource appInsightsComponents 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
}

resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-15' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: 'app' 
  dependsOn: [appInsightsComponents]
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: ''
      pythonVersion: '3.11'
    }
    storageAccountRequired: false
    
    reserved: true
  }

}
output appServicePlanId string = appServicePlan.name
output appInsightsId string = appInsightsComponents.name
output webAppId string = webApplication.name



Choose Open Bicep Visualizer from option after right clicking the file.
OR
You can click icon at the right top corner also to visualize the bicep file.

OUTPUT:

